# Finding log likelihood

Tags: probability, probability-theory, density-function, log-likelihood

Consider $X_1,X_2,…,X_n\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

The density of a single $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is
$$f_{X_i}(x_i;\mu,\sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{−(x_i−\mu)^2}{2σ^2}\right).$$

How do I find the log-likelihood $\ln(L(\mu,\sigma^2|x_1,…,x_n))$?

Comment: Do you know how the likelihood $L$ is defined? (Be careful with the indices)

Comment: @BenjaminWang I'm not sure, can you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
L(\mu, \sigma^2)&=\prod_{i=1}^n f_{X_i}(x_i)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(\frac{−(x_i−\mu)^2}{2σ^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2})^n}\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{−(x_i−\mu)^2}{2σ^2}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

So we have
$$\begin{align}
\ln L(\mu, \sigma^2)&=\underbrace{-n\ln(\sqrt{2\pi})}_{\text{constant}} - n\ln(\sqrt{\sigma^2}) + \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{−(x_i−\mu)^2}{2σ^2}\\
\end{align}
$$